# Unable to center a Picker using SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to make a picker in SwiftUI and functionally its working great. But for whatever reason it squeezes the title onto the left side of the picker, but I just want to picker to be centred in the view.

Here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct FancyPicker: View {
    let name: String
    let options: [String]
    let doneText = "Done"
    let onSelection: (String)->Void

    @State private var selection = 0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text(name)
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {
                    self.onSelection(self.options[self.selection])
                }, label: {
                    Text(doneText)
                })
            }.padding()

            Picker(selection: $selection, label: EmptyView()) {
                ForEach(0 ..< options.count) { index in
                    Text(self.options[index]).tag(index)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct FancyPicker_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        FancyPicker(name: "Test Picker", options: ["One", "Two", "Three"]) { selection in
            print("Selected \(selection)")
        }
    }
}
```

You can notice I have the pickers label set to an `EmptyView` and here is what the output looks like:

[image: Ugly Picker View]

Is there anyway to get rid of the ugly padding on the left side? There is also extra ugly padding above and below the picker but I can worry about that another day...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `.labelsHidden()` to hide the Picker's label.

Even if the label is hidden, I'd recommend adding a descriptive label so the label can be used by screen readers.

([credit](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/selecting-dates-and-times-with-datepicker))

Answer (score 5):

You have to hide the labels in order to center the picker. You can also edit a height and clip it to have a custom picker height.

```
var body: some View {
  VStack {

    Picker(selection: $selection, label: Text("") {
      ForEach(0 ..< options.count) {
        Text(self.options[$0]).tag($0)
      }
    }
    .labelsHidden()
    .frame(height: 50)
    .clipped()
  }
}
```

Comment: Ended up using it without the height and without the clipped since i thought the end result was cleaner - but looks much better now, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have to hide label of PickerView.

```
 Picker(selection: $selection, label: EmptyView()) {
            ForEach(0 ..< options.count) { index in
                Text(self.options[index]).tag(index)
            }
        }.labelsHidden()
```